# Configuring elasticsearch to store metrics

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, monitoring, metrics

I want to store metrics in ES. At the moment, I am already storing logs there with Logstash. I am going to use the same Logstash instance to store metrics, but metrics will be collected by collectd.

According to this [topic](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-as-a-time-series-data-store), I need to tune up my ES before I will start storing metrics there (like mapping types and etc).

So, my **question is** - what will be better:

- Separate logs and metrics into a different indices?
- Separate logs and metrics into a different instances of ES?

I have never done type mapping before, so it is not clear for me - how should I implement this.

Feel free to give me **any** **advice** you have, I would be really happy to get your opinion regarding my problem.

Comment: What did you do in the end? how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fit a round hole in a square peg. ElasticSearch indexes documents (events, logs, files, etc). It is not a metric ingest engine. This is the reason people pair it with other tools. You'd want to look at metric and time series based stores if you are building your own.

For example at AppDynamics under the covers we use ElasicSearch as one of our 3 backends to store events and logs for example, the other two are MySQL (Metadata/configuration of our tool), Cassandra on HDFS for metrics.

In the open source world you may want to look at Graphite, or some of the other associated metric stores which are better suited for your use case.

Comment: Hey Jonah! Thank you for your attention! Please take a look at these links: 1) Space consumption ES vs InfluxDB (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elk-vs-grafana-influxdb/1686/25)
2) CERN's performance comparison between Elasticsearch, InfluxDB and OpenTSDB. (http://cds.cern.ch/record/2011172/files/LHCb-TALK-2015-060.pdf).  I find the idea of using ES as TSDB quite reasonable.